# Getting two filter table dropdowns to work at same time

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to make the location filter dropdown and category dropdown work at the same time so that table values show up according to both location and category, but the displayDate function for this isn't working. Here's the website: https://opportunities.sarahlim3.repl.co/discover.html Here's the code for the page:

```
<select id="mylist" class='form-control'>
      <option value="">Filter by location</option>

 <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
            <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
</select> 




<select id="categorylist" class='form-control'>
    <option value="">Filter by category</option>

 <option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option>
            <option value="Science">Science</option>
            <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
           <option value="Business/Marketing">Business/Marketing</option>
            <option value="Music">Music</option>
            <option value="Art">Art</option>
           <option value="All STEM fields">All STEM fields</option>
</select> 
<button onclick="filterTable()">Submit</button>

    <table id="show" style="padding:30px; width:90%;" class="internshipInfo">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Internship name</th>
           <th>Internship location</th>
           <th>Internship category</th>
           <th>Internship link</th>
  <th>Internship deadline</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
     </table>
     
<script>
function searchFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("searchList");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("show");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
    
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      
    }
  }
}
</script>


<script>
function filterTable() {
  var input, input2 filter, filter2, table, tr, td, i, test;
  input = document.getElementById("mylist");
  input2 = document.getElementById("categorylist");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  filter2 = input2.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("show");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    test = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]
    if (td) {
      if (td.toUpperCase() === filter && test.toUpperCase() === filter2) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
         
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      
      }
      
    }       
  }


}
</script>
```

Comment: it would help if you added some data as well

Answer (score -2):

the if statement should be like that

```
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() === filter.toUpperCase() && test.innerHTML.toUpperCase() === filter2.toUpperCase())
```